# added object not updated in UITableView using SQlite database

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite

I have a SQL database which I can display on a UITableView. But if try to add any object it is not updated in UITableView. It is updated only after application is restarted. 
When I delete objects from UITableView there is inbuilt method which does deleting
is `if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)` is there any such methods 
for adding objects also?

My addition methods are as follows:

```
static sqlite3 *addStmt = nil;   

- (void) add_Place:(Place *)PlaceObj {

    NSLog(@"Super add called");

    //Add it to the database.
    [PlaceObj addPlace];

    //Add it to the coffee array.
    [PlacesArray addObject:PlaceObj];
}

- (void) addPlace {


    NSLog(@"addplace called");
    if(addStmt == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"inside addstmt");
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO places_table ( PlaceName, PlaceAddress) Values (?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"error inside if loop");
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"outside if Loop") ;

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [PlaceName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [PlaceAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));;
    }
    //  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
    {
        //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
        PlaceID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_last_insert_rowid") ;
    }

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following manner. After you add the object just call the `ReloadData` UITableView Method and it will reload the table again. So there is no need To restart the application again.

```
    static sqlite3 *addStmt = nil;   

    - (void) add_Place:(Place *)PlaceObj {

        NSLog(@"Super add called");

        //Add it to the database.
        [PlaceObj addPlace];

        //Add it to the coffee array.
        [PlacesArray addObject:PlaceObj];
        [TableView ReloadData];
    }

    - (void) addPlace {


        NSLog(@"addplace called");
        if(addStmt == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"inside addstmt");
            const char *sql = "INSERT INTO places_table ( PlaceName, PlaceAddress) Values (?,?)";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"error inside if loop");
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            }
        }

        NSLog(@"outside if Loop") ;

        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [PlaceName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [PlaceAddress UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));;
        }
        //  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
        {
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            PlaceID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
            NSLog(@"sqlite3_last_insert_rowid") ;
        }

        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks you very much Srinivas. I added [self.tableView reloadData] on "viewWillAppear" method I code was running fine.  When I declared [self.tableView reloadData] on place you mentioned there was compilation error. But that is my fault as I didn't gave full information on where are all functions defined and from where they are called. But I read about "reloadData" method and found the answer. Thank You very much for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a). This will add the rows with a smooth animation of your choosing. This will only work if your `UITableViewDataSource` is coded properly however.

Comment: Thanks for your response jin. [self.tableView reloadData] worked perfectly fine for me